# Как сделать квадратные кнопки, которые будут растягиваться на весь экран?

Tags: java, android, xml

Как в Android сделать два столбца из кнопок, которые будут заполнять экран, в зависимости от его размеров? Можно ли это сделать только в .xml файле или же нужно писать код в .java?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант это сделать горизонтальный `LinearLayout` и задать кнопкам не ширину, а веса. И этот `LinearLayout` нужно положить в корневой. Для корневого можно взять вертикальный `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего воспользоваться GridLayout так как LinearLayout требует много ресурсов от устройства. В GridLayout Вы задаете необходимое количество строк и стобцов. Вот пример:

```
android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity"
app:columnCount="2"
app:rowCount="5"
```

Ниже должны быть перечислены элементы которыми Вы заполняете layout. Для растяжения на весь экран необходимо всем элементам задать такие характеристики:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

[Здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php) неплохо описано как работать с GridLayout.